# Spring without XML on Karaf

Tags: spring, osgi, apache-karaf

I have WAR that need to be deployed on karaf. The war uses spring also it is written in servlet3 standards, using annotations both for servlets and spring(viz. no web.xml and other xmls).
When I Deploy the the web application, the web bundle starts without any erros. But the problem is I cannot access the application from Webbrowser(Was able to access when I deployed in tomcat 7).
I Installed the following features

1. spring(3.2.11.RELEASE_1)
2. spring-web
3. war
4. http
5. spring-dm(dont know whether its required actually)
6. pax-war.

This is the bundle plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
            <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
            <Export-Package>com.welflex.notes,com.welflex.notes.rest.*, com.welflex.notes.spring.security</Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
            <Web-ContextPath>/osgiwar</Web-ContextPath>
            <_wab>src/main/webapp</_wab>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <supportedProjectTypes>
            <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
            <supportedProjectType>feature</supportedProjectType>
            <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
        </supportedProjectTypes>
        <aggregateFeatures>true</aggregateFeatures>
        <includeTransitiveDependency>true</includeTransitiveDependency>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is the result of the commands that i issued in karaf.

```
karaf@root(feature)> web:list
ID  | State       | Web-State   | Level | Web-ContextPath | Name                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
271 | Active      | Deployed    | 80    | /osgiwar        | Notes-webapp (1.0.0)

karaf@root(feature)> http:list
ID  | Servlet                                   | Servlet-Name    | State       | Alias               | Url                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
254 | Proxy162313f6_071f_4c85_800e_359cd95ed681 | ServletModel-10 | Deployed    | /features           | [/features/*]                                              
271 | JspServletWrapper                         | jsp             | Deployed    |                     | [*.jsp, *.jspx, *.jspf, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPX, *.JSPF, *.XSP]
271 | ResourceServlet                           | default         | Deployed    | /                   | [/]                                                        
252 | ResourceServlet                           | /res            | Deployed    | /system/console/res | [/system/console/res/*]                                    
252 | KarafOsgiManager                          | ServletModel-2  | Undeployed  | /system/console     | [/system/console/*]                                        
255 | Proxy5832af65_c1ab_4f7a_b858_6b151c28af79 | ServletModel-12 | Deployed    | /gogo               | [/gogo/*]                                                  
121 | CXFNonSpringServlet                       | ServletModel-14 | Deployed    | /cxf                | [/cxf/*]                                                    
252 | KarafOsgiManager                          | ServletModel-5  | Deployed    | /system/console     | [/system/console/*]                                        
253 | Proxy0096643a_4c37_499e_a368_e90dd315172f | ServletModel-8  | Deployed    | /instance           | [/instance/*]
```

Is it possible deploy this spring webapplication on the Karaf.??? ... Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong here..

Thanks,
NA